# Excel converts datetime to other format where days are low enough to be months

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, date-time

I live in europe and our datetime format is usually dd/MM/yyy
I have an excel spreadsheet where I have ALOT of dates

But for reasons I do not know, Excel converts where (dd < 12) to mm/dd/yyyy - which gives me inconsistent data (ofcourse) see picture below

[image]

How do I disable this?!

Comment: See if the Local settings of your PC set to dd/MM/YY in your PC from Control panel >> Regional settings (Im assuming you are using Windows 7)

Comment: Yes my format is as it should be dd/MM/YY

Comment: When does this 'convert' occur? I mean, does it happen when you paste dates in? What are you expecting to happen? Does converting the document to use `Text` fix it (I assume not)

Comment: I insert the data programatically - the data is correct in my MSSQL table - correct formatting - once it hits the excel sheet - the dates where dd is lower than 12 gets reformattet. which is why i assume its an excel "issue"

Comment: Yes, I agree. You could, as a quick hack, convert the data to a string (assuming it's a `DateTime` in the DB)?

Comment: The data in the SQL table are varchars - as some of them feature a "never".
I've tried converting columns to text - to no avail

Ill try to convert the data to DateTime and add a null instead of Never

Comment: no dice - but when i try to "Clear Formats" - the strings that has been converted - get formatted to some similar to 42127,4197569444

Answer (score 0):

I've located the issue! -
Apparently, by default (which can not be turned off) Excel says "Hey, I recognize that data type, ill convert it, for your convenience" (Gee thanks excel!)

You can either format all cells as text
CTRL+A => CTRL+1 => Select: Number_tab...Category: Text => OK

or

you can insert data into a cell with an apostrophe (') before. So the data you insert is
"'02/12/2015" excel says "Oh so you want a string?"

Apparently the excel team calls it "AutoCorrect"